# Object.getPrototypeOf vs .prototype

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-5

Consider the following code:

```
function Person(a,b){
    this.a = a;
    this.b = b;
};


Object.getPrototypeOf(Person) === Person.prototype;  // gives false
```

Should not they be equal ?

Comment: No; they mean different things.  See the documentation.  In particular, `obj.prototype` doesn't exist.

Comment: @SLaks question has been revised

Comment: `Object.getPrototypeOf(Person) == Function.prototype`. `Object.getPrototype(new Person) == Person.prototype`.

Comment: @BreakingBenjamin: Still no.  See the documentation.

Comment: @Bergi , yes but why give different values when both things should point out to prototype of the Person only which should be Function.prototype.

Comment: That's not what `Person.prototype` means.  See the documentation.

Comment: The Object.getPrototypeOf() method returns the prototype (i.e. the value of the internal [[Prototype]] property) of the specified object. So, basically it expects an object in the argument. So, Object.getPrototypeOf(new Person) would give you the correct prototype you were looking for.  Object.getPrototypeOf(Person) just gives you back the prototype of Person constructor function as functions are also objects in JS.

Comment: Ok ,I got it. 'prototype' is a property of a Function object. It is the prototype of all the objects that are constructed by that function. Object.getPrototypeOf() gives the prototype of the object.

Comment: @BreakingBenjamin The `.prototype` property is not the link to the object from which properties are inherited.

Comment: @Bergi,  yes it is (if I am right) except I have to use it on constructor and not the object instances. :)